# Show image paperclip after query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a column called resolution_image type boolean in the paperclip images table. I want to show the image where the field resolution_image is true, how do i show this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some more details on your specific naming convention, but let's assume the following:

1. You have a model with a paperclip attachment named `model_with_image_attachment`
2. That model has an attachment which you've named `attachment_name`

This would display the image when the `resolution_image` attribute is `true`:

```
<%= image_tag model_with_image_attachment.attachment_name.url if model_with_image_attachment.resolution_image %>
```

Comment: The model is Image and the attachment_name is image.

Comment: The model image is polymorphic

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= image_tag @model.picture.url if @model.resolution_image %>
```